# How to validate white spaces only on the textboxes of asp.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net

There are 4 textboxes for users to enter criteria to search information from our database on the asp.net web page. Users can enter on one textbox or two textbox or three or four or don't enter anything to search all but not allow the user to enter white space(s) only on the textboxes.

How do I use a validator to validate the white space(s)?

Comment: Many possibilities, do you use jquery.validate ? otherwise you want to writte it in c# or javascript or bot h?

Comment: It is better to use a validator to validate it

Comment: agree with you but there is many sorts of validators, jquery, javascript, c# ... which one ?

Comment: I think is it possible to use a RegularExpressionValidator? Thank you.